# Is there a site that allows you to produce royalty free digital/techno music that you can use commercially?

Tags: webapp-rec, music

Does anyone know of a free site which allows you to:

- drag and drop instruments and beats onto a timeline
- download your song as an mp3 royalty free so that you can include it in commercial software products such as educational games?

Comment: I'm might be a good idea to remove "best" from the title - it might help to avoid the question being closed as "subjective and argumentative".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like Aviary.com's [Roc](http://aviary.com/tools/music-creator) is what you're looking for?

Comment: that's pretty easy to use, just created http://aviary.com/artists/edwardta/creations/simplebeat, but I don't understand how I can make a song with more than 8 measures, am I missing something?

Comment: I posted a question about the 8-measure limitation in case it gets answered in the future, here it is: http://aviary.com/thread?tid=4440